# Share & track code snippets in-house?

Tags: code-snippets, sharing

Is there an online tool to share and track code-snippets between a team of developers?

My team mate is sitting right next to me and GTalk isn't really adequate for pasting larger snippets.

How can I "copy-paste" or drag a source file or snippet to share between coders? It should remember all previous snippets and be available to the whole team. I'd rather not resort to email. Or do I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 1):

Please try http://codepad.org/

Comment: This does not meet the requirements. It is neither in-house nor does it make all previous snippets available to the team.

Comment: If all previous snippets are public, they are accessible through the URL

Comment: I love codepad (+1). As a consultant, I use it a lot, and often use it with customers.

Answer (score 1):

Try [www.ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com). use a private post for sharing between your developers